# Deleting or listing least frequently played songs in Google Play Music

Tags: music, google-play-music

I'm starting to hit the limits of my storage space. My device is mostly filled with music, so I'd like to remove songs I don't listen to anymore, without having to painfully scroll down the list and delete them one by one.

Does Google Play Music have some way to at least list the least frequently played songs, or is there an additional music management app I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no feature in Google Play Music that lets you delete songs you don't listen to. AFAIK there is no app that does the same too.

Comment: Uh, that's too bad... I'll write an app for that then! :)